# How to set cv::Mat to zero where another matrix is nonzero?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.3

I have a matrix `D` which I would like to set to zero where another matrix `T` is zero and keep intact otherwise. In numpy, I'd do this:

```
D[T==0]=0;
```

but with `cv::Mat`, not sure how to do it. I tried this:

```
D&=(T!=0);
```

with this result:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type()) in gemm, file /build/opencv-AuXD2R/opencv-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 1558
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-AuXD2R/opencv-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:1558: error: (-215) type == B.type() in function gemm
```

Is the problem that I am mixing numeric types? I also tried this then (`D` is `CV_32F` as well, which I verified by outputting `T.type()`, `5`):

```
cv::Mat TnotZero;
cv::Mat(T!=0).convertTo(TnotZero,CV_32F);
D&=TnotZero;
```

with the same result.

What is the solution?

Comment: Use [`Mat::setTo()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) with the `mask` parameter. You can invert the mask first with [`cv::bitwise_not()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not).

Comment: Thanks, very good tip for opencv beginner :)